# Maven - 'override' not work in external settings

Tags: maven

I am using spring boot in my app like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

In my external settings.xml I defined resource plugin like this:

```
     <profile>
        <activation>
          <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <id>dev</id>
        ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>            
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                      <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>^^</delimiter>
                      </delimiters>
                      <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

and this not work. When I move it to my pom it works. I know that settings file is red because dev properties are taken from it. What is wrong?

Comment: Defining plugins in settings.xml is simple not possible. And why don't you do that in your pom file...

Comment: Its fix for ide bug - I can't change delimiter for all. I added maven-resources-plugin in settings with specified conf and it works.

Comment: In settings is a bad idea..put things like this into your pom file otherwise it works not everywhere......